# Put echo in background: url($variable)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have function like this:

```
function abc(){

if ( of_get_option('pattern_option') != '' ) {

    $pattern = of_get_option('pattern_option');

    $custom_pattern = '

    html{
        background: url('.echo $pattern .') repeat !important;  
    }
    .page_site{
        background: url($pattern) repeat !important; 
    }
   ';
};
};
```

How can I echo background URL, I try in many ways and nothing helps, always get parse error.

Thanks For Your Time

Comment: Thanks for -1 ... click more :/

Comment: I hate the guys who downvote someone without explaining why. Back to topic. Have you tried this: background: url('.$pattern.') repeat !important; and  background: url('.$pattern.') repeat !important;

Comment: Yep, try it....

Comment: Hope your method binding in `<style></style>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to concat your `$pattern` variable into the string itself using the [`.` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

So in other words,

```
$custom_pattern = '
    html{
        background: url('.$pattern.') repeat !important;  
    }
    .page_site{
        background: url('.$pattern.') repeat !important; 
    }
';
```

Comment: But You say it's right way and I must search for "bug" in other place?

Comment: Yes @michael, I'd say it should be working but you'd have to check where  `of_get_option('pattern_option')` is looking for your value you're expecting.  :-)

Comment: I'd probably just do a `var_dump($pattern)` and see what it's *really* sending back. Could you share your return value in the original post?

Comment: Ok I got it ... as this is wordPress I put to late wp_add_inline_style .... but Thanks for Your Time

Comment: Oh, cool. You could always create your own answer to this post so that other people that happen to stumble upon it can see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( of_get_option('pattern_option') != '' ) {

$pattern = of_get_option('pattern_option');

$custom_pattern = '
  html{
    background: url('. $pattern .') repeat !important;  
  }
  .page_site{
    background: url(' . $pattern . ') repeat !important; 
  }'; 
}
```

Try it like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc() {
    if (of_get_option('pattern_option') != '') {
        $pattern = of_get_option('pattern_option');

        $custom_pattern  = 'html {';
        $custom_pattern .= '    background: url(' . $pattern . ') repeat !important;';
        $custom_pattern .= '}';
        $custom_pattern .= '.page_site {';
        $custom_pattern .= '    background: url('. $pattern . ') repeat !important;';
        $custom_pattern .= '}';
    }
}
```